# How to handle navigation to a specific view when user presses notification in Swift UI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around data flow in Swift UI.  The core of my issue seems to be that I need to execute a function which lives in my main app file from within my `userNotificationCenter` function in a delegate class I created.

I've implemented a janky way of navigating the user and executing a block of code when the user taps on a daily notification in my app.

The goal is to navigate to a 'DayView' tab 2 of the main app screen while simultaneously selecting todays date as the active day when the user presses the notification.

I've achieved this by attaching a static function to my NotificationService class and updating that property from the main app file in a .task block:

```
@StateObject private var planStore = PlanStore()
func handleDailyNotificationPressed() {
  planStore.tabSelection = 2;
  planStore.selectToday()
}

.task {
  // Connect notificationHandling callback to notificationService
  // TODO find a less janky way to execute this callback (non static method)
  NotificationService.onNotificationPressed = handleDailyNotificationPressed
}
```

In my NotificationService, I use the following code to call the static method that I jankily assigned above.  This works, but feels very incorrect, data flow wise.  Any suggestions on how to make this cleaner?

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, willFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        return true
    }
    
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        print("Daily notification received -- navigating to Today View")
        NotificationService.onNotificationPressed()
        completionHandler()
    }
}

class NotificationService: ObservableObject {
    
    static var onNotificationPressed: () -> Void = {}
```

Comment: The approach is mostly OK. I would have the function inside the `PlanStore` object, rather in the view.  Then the notification observer can also be inside `PlanStore`.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to handle notifications like deep links. Any Notifications can contain a deep link url to easily handle navigation to any view in your application and by this you have a abstract and maintainable code.

Here is a simple example:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
    self.application(application, didReceiveRemoteNotification: userInfo) { [weak self] _ in
        guard let self else { return }
        if let url = self.exportUrlFrom(data: userInfo) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url)
        } else {
            assertionFailure("push notification data is not valid.")
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** `export url from data` is just a simple protocol to export the deep link url from user info dictionary. **In this case you have to use another delegate for receiving notifications.**

In the other hand, you have to handle deep link:

```
lazy var navigator = Navigator()

func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey: Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        guard navigator.present(url) != nil else { return false }
        return true
    }
```

The rest of this handled by Navigator. Navigator help you to navigate throughout view controllers simple and clear. Add [URLNavigator](https://github.com/devxoul/URLNavigator) to your project, read its article and implement it.